# Exit Just One Cell and Continue Running Rest of Cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently running a function for multiple process areas of a production facility. Unfortunately, I cannot send the full code as it contains a lot of confidential information from the customer.

Each area is checked with a function in different cells of a ipynb in Jupyter and I ran into an issue were the production for an area is 0 for the given period. My solution is to use sys.exit(0) in the function if the production is 0 for the given period.

This works to stop the cell and print the error. However, I then run into the issue where the other cells below don't run because of the exit command.

**Is there any way that you can stop the function from running with a check like the one below and also keep it from interrupting entire your notebook? See the attached image to see what I'm referencing. The code blow is inside the function I'm calling.**

```
if len(df_prod.values()) == 0:
     print('There is no data for the given time')
     sys.exit(0)
else:
    continue
```

P.S. My apologies if this isn't clear. I'm pretty new to coding and even newer to stackoverflow! Please let me know any best practices or if you need any clarification.

EDIT:
The picture below may help clarify.

Image showing the issue. Outputs were hidden from cell 4.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! A few points that might need clarification: Jupyter notebooks (like most scripts) are meant to be run sequentially, not in parallel. How are these functions operating? Is there supposed to be a continuous while loop that's happening? Are they calling another script? Why do you need to use `exit()` instead of just `return` to end the function run?

Comment: Hello, these functions are being called from a .py file located in the same folder as the .ipynb. The function is sequential and it runs through the .py file to generate a report at the end essentially. I want the cells to operate sequentially, not in parallel. Basically, when cell 4 runs, then cell 5 runs, and if i encounter an error then i want it to move to the next cell. Can you use return in the middle of a python function?

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I didn't even think of using return in that if statement. That solved the problem! Thank you so much G. Anderson! I'm not sure how to make that comment as the solution.

Comment: Glad I could help! I added the solution as an answer so you can accept it if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to run a function until a certain result is achieved, then rather than using `sys.exit(0)` to stop running all code just `return` from the function so the script can move on to running the next